# Can't access to docker itzg/minecraft-server on dedicated server

Tags: docker, ubuntu, minecraft, dedicated-server

I am trying to host a Minecraft server in a docker container on a dedicated server (Ubuntu 20.04).
I am using the itzg/minecraft-server image with docker-compose to create my container.
I have no errors when creating the container nor when launching the minecraft server in the container logs. BUT when I connect to the server with the public ip of my vps and port 25565, I have

> Can't connect to server:
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection
> timed out: no further information:

I also tried to start the server as idzg suggests, following this instructions :

> To simply use the latest stable version, run
>
> docker run -d -p 25565:25565 --name mc itzg/minecraft-server
>
> where the standard server port, 25565, will be exposed on your host
> machine.

but the problem is the same

The container is OK

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                   COMMAND    CREATED          STATUS                    PORTS                                                      NAMES
21c67ba9a3c2   itzg/minecraft-server   "/start"   16 minutes ago   Up 16 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:25565->25565/tcp, :::25565->25565/tcp, 25575/tcp   mc
```

Server logs is OK

```
[10:42:11] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 99%
[10:42:11] [Server thread/INFO]: Time elapsed: 14039 ms
[10:42:11] [Server thread/INFO]: Done (14.161s)! For help, type "help"
[10:42:11] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting remote control listener
[10:42:11] [Server thread/INFO]: Thread RCON Listener started
[10:42:11] [Server thread/INFO]: RCON running on 0.0.0.0:25575
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  mc:
    container_name: mc
    image: itzg/minecraft-server
    ports:
      - 25565:25565
    environment:
      EULA: "TRUE"
    volumes:
      # attach a directory relative to the directory containing this compose file
      - /home/neuromob/minecraft-server/data_tmp:/data
```

Additionally, I have a second container with a nginx and node web server to build a vue.js project. This container is still down when I tried to start my Minecraft server, but I prefer to specify it if ever it can conflict for the connection ... ? But I don't think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For people who have the same problem, I solved it by simply opening port 25565 on the VPS host site